# Sending data 2 ways between client and server

Tags: java, networking, client-server

As the name suggests could anyone explain how to allow a client to communicate with a server application (so they both send and receive data), I would mainly like to allow the use of Strings to be sent and received for a house messaging service. Note could this try not to include the use of Http networking.

Comment: Java sockets http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html

Comment: Seems you are looking for Sockets-based solution; take a look at this tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html

Comment: I looked at the links and they feel like what I need, Thanks!

Comment: *"--Picaxmad"*  Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could either use plain sockets or Java's Remote Method Invocation (RMI) which is a higher level of abstraction. Oracle has a [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html) on writing a simple client/-server application with RMI. Note: since RMI is proprietary, you need to use Java on both sides (client and server). If this is not possible, you can use sockets as desrcibed [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/index.html).

Comment: I think using RMI is excessive for the problem which was described.

Comment: You are dead right, especially if he only wants to transmit strings. But on the other hand, RMI is not that sophisticated and could be useful if he wants to expand his messaging later on. I just wanted to show him two basic approaches (sockets and rmi).